# 'at very high altitude', 'at very high altitudes': both are okay in this sentence?

Tags: zero-article, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

I'd like to know and ask whether both the sentences below are correct.

- ***At very high altitude** you will have difficulty breathing.*
- ***At very high altitudes** you will have difficulty breathing.*

My thoughts are as follows: since the word *altitude* has both countable and uncountable uses as described below by [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/altitude?q=altitude), either will be okay and the two sentences seem to have no difference at all.

[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/altitude?q=altitude)'s second definition for **altitude(noun)**:

> ​[countable, usually plural, uncountable] a place that is high above sea level, e.g. *Snow leopards live at high altitudes*
> e.g. *The athletes trained at altitude in Mexico City*

Comment: In your context, [*both forms are in common use*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=At+high+altitude%2CAt+a+high+altitude%2CAt+high+altitudes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAt%20high%20altitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAt%20a%20high%20altitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAt%20high%20altitudes%3B%2Cc0) and mean exactly the same when used as an adverbial clause to start a sentence. There's also the singular form ***with an indefinite article*** - which is syntactically fine, albeit far less common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really appreciate each and every comment of yours. Your comments have been of great help also in other questions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the plural *altitudes* depends on whether you mean more than one altitude.

'An altitude' is a *specific* measurement, so any given altitude is *singular*.

For example:

> The plane is flying at an altitude of 30,000 feet.

However, you could refer to a variety of different measurements, in which case you would use the plural.

For example:

> The plane is capable of flying at high altitudes.
> *(ie it could fly at 32,000ft 34,000ft, 36,000ft etc)*

In your example, either work - although I would go for the plural, because it makes it a broader statement - 'high altitudes' is a *range* where this would occur.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer.:) It helps a lot.

Your answer clears up the uses of a singular and a plural. But how about the version with an uncountable noun, which is just *altitude* without any article in the first sentence I asked about? I'd like to ask for your thought on it, if I may ask.